# Azure Function v2 - how to load configuration as singelton?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm migrating an Azure Function from v1 (.NET 4.7) to v2 (.NET Standard 2). In the v1 version I was using some static variables which I read from the config like this to get a singleton (of a Cosmos DB client)

```
private static string cosmosDbUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDb.Uri"];
//...
private static MyCosmosDbClient cosmosDbClient = new MyCosmosDbClient(cosmosDbUri, ...);
```

For v2 I would switch to ConfigurationBuilder for my config:

```
private static IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

Now there is the problem that this needs the [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function), which I only get (or know how to get), when the function is executed.

So my question is, how to tackle this best? Build an `Init(ExecutionContext context)` method that I would call only if the config was not yet loaded or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace `context.FunctionAppDirectory` with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

At least, that works locally and that's exactly where you need `local.settings.json` to work, so this change should be safe.

Comment: @silent same situation here + lazy, does it work when deployed to Azure? Thanks!

Comment: @qwertoyo yes, because in Azure the application settings get injected as Environment Variables. That's why you have the part `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`in there

Comment: True, local.settings.json is only for local dev. Thanks!

Comment: This might have just saved me from a very long night!

Comment: It does not work this helps https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1817#issuecomment-418430676